# How to pass route param while using Inertia manual visit

Tags: vuejs3, inertiajs, laravel-9

How can I pass the route param while using Inertia manual visit, for example:

> Route:

```
Route::post('/explore/gallery/like/{$post}', [ExploreController::class, 'likeToggle'])
    ->name('explore.post.like');
```

> Component:

```
Inertia.visit(route('explore.post.like'),
                {
                    method: 'post',
                    preserveScroll: true,
                    data: {
                        $post: this.id
                    },
                },
            );
```

but is shows the error tho,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A simple solution would be:**

```
Inertia.post(route('explore.post.like', [this.id, 'if you have other params']), {}, {
                preserveScroll: true,
            });
```

**Pls make sure the order is correct, follow the order of your route's param**

Answer (score 2):

Error occur in Ziggy, and says you need pass $post,

Ok, Change `route('explore.post.like')` to `route('explore.post.like', this.id)`

According Ziggy documentation you can also use like :

```
route('explore.post.like', this.id)
route('explore.post.like', [this.id])
route('explore.post.like', { $post: this.id })
```

Comment: Thx for your answer.